# react redux step workflows

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a step workflow. First you select a task, then, you select a snapshot, ...

```
class RestorePage extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { system_id: systemId } = this.props.params;
        const { setStep, fetchSystem } = this.props;
        const { query } = this.props.location;

        if (!query.zfbrowser_restore) {
            fetchSystem(systemId);
            setStep(STEPS.SELECT_TASK);
        } else {
            setStep(STEPS.RESTORE_FORM);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { step, isLoadingSystem } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="__page-title" data-ztest="restore_title">Restore</h1>
                {(() => {
                    if (isLoadingSystem) {
                        return (<Spinner>Loading System...</Spinner>);
                    }

                    switch (step) {
                        case STEPS.SELECT_TASK:
                            return <Tasks />;
                        case STEPS.SELECT_SNAPSHOT:
                            return <Snapshots />;
                        case STEPS.FILE_BROWSER:
                            return <FileBrowser />;
                        case STEPS.RESTORE_FORM:
                            return <Form />;
                        default:
                            return (<div>Invalid Step</div>);
                    }
                })()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm storing the application state step in redux's store (and then, localStorage). I'm having issues with navigating away and coming back. It goes to the old step. A stale value. I've thought about moving the step state into this.step, but that'd require a forceUpdate. I've also though about storing it in react-router as part of the URL. I'm not sure if that'd be a good idea though because I'd have to have url changes. Each step requires the previous step for it's data, so if I change the url and go back to it, I'll have to fetch everything over again.

Is there any way to set the initial step? I've tried doing it in componentWillUpdate, but it still renders the old step prior to getting the update.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I moved the step to react-router. That appears to work fine